# удаление CR на конце строки, чтобы только LF остался

Tags: python

записываю строку в файл, в виде `"".join((c.upper() if x & (1 << i) else c) for i, c in enumerate(word)).rstrip() + '\n'`. но при просмотре файла в notepad++ такая картина

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как можно при записи убрать CR на конце, чтобы оставить лишь LF?

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47384741/17512180) описано решение вашей проблемы:

```
with open('text.txt', 'w', newline='\n') as f:
```

[image: как то так]